# Mac OS Safari 12 images with svg source displaying scrollbars

Tags: html, css, macos, svg, safari

Weird problem we have run into where some svg images are displaying scrollbars. You can't interact with the scroll, they are almost part of the image. Anyone come across this before or have any ideas?
The image has a round height and width, only happens on certain machines. Got 2 macbooks, both running high sierra and Safari 12, only happens on 1. If you zoom into the page the actual scrollbar is zoomed too, so it is almost like the scroll is part of the image.

You can see an example of this here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WarMLp

```
<img src="http://www.boxmodeldigital.com/Assets/images/logos/main__logo.svg" alt"" />
```

[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide an [MCVE] so we can reproduce on our own. Also, you can check [webkit's bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org) if they have anything like that already reported, and if they don't, file a new report.

Comment: @Kaiido Added an example. Thanks

Comment: So, this is probably a bug indeed (I could repro while switching my system pref to Show scroll bars: always on Safari12.0 macOs 10.12). But in their defense, you have a `overflow="scroll"` attribute on your root node. What did you expect exactly from this? (Can't repro on other svg that don't have this attribute, so simply remove it should fix your issue).

Comment: @Kaiido I haven't added overflow scroll to anything. That codepen example was just to show an example of it happening. I have submitted a bug report. Thanks

Comment: Yes, your [linked svg image](http://www.boxmodeldigital.com/Assets/images/logos/main__logo.svg) has this attribute. Check the sources: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="181.6" height="27.1" viewBox="0 0 181.6 27.1" overflow="scroll"><style>...`

Comment: @Kaiido yep, I get you. Cheers, Guessing this has come from the illustrator export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bug indeed (I could repro while switching my system pref to *Show scroll bars: always* on Safari12.0 macOs 10.12).

But in their defense, you have a `overflow="scroll"` attribute on your root node.
Simply removing it should fix your issue:

```js
var source = `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" overflow="scroll">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" ry="15" />
</svg>`

buggy.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([source], {type: 'image/svg+xml'}));
// remove the attribute
source = source.replace(' overflow="scroll"', '');
fixed.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([source], {type: 'image/svg+xml'}));
```

```css
img{width:calc(50vmin - 4px); margin: 1px}
```

```html
<img id="buggy"><img id="fixed">
```

---

---

Here is a screenshot of the StackSnippet's result on my Safari 12.0.
[image: Screenshot of the StackSnippet's result on Safari 12.0 showing the first image with scrollbars, and the second without.]

Comment: thanks for this, this has sorted it. Think the overflow scroll has come from the illustrator export. Thanks